# JavaScript object "disappears"

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to use a simple below function from jQuery function:

```
var getLocation =  function(address) {
    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            var latitude = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
            var longitude = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
            console.log('coordinates: ' + latitude, longitude);
            return {latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude};
        }
        console.log('maps are not OK');
        return undefined;
    });
}
```

I see the coordinates printed in the browser console.

However, the function calling it gets undefined. Below is my invocation:

```
var loc = getLocation($('#origin').val());
```

The loc is always undefined, even though inside getLocation() coordinates appear to be fine.

Please advise what I am doing wrong. Tried silly things, like adding quotes around latitude and longitude etc. Does not seem to make a difference.

Thank you.

Comment: You arent actually returning anything in the getLocation function, which will set the variable loc to undefined

Comment: not close and no cigar :)

Comment: `geocode()` is an asynchronous method. You need to place all code reliant on its response in the callback parameter - you cannot return its value directly.